# Export LibreOffice document comments as PDF annotations

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, comments, annotations

I would like to export to PDF a particular LibreOffice document that has many comments without losing them. According to the [manual](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/shared/01/ref_pdf_export.html?DbPAR=SHARED) this should be possible:

> **Comments as PDF annotations**
>
> Select to export comments of Writer and
> Calc documents as PDF annotations.
>
> To export comments of Writer documents as they are shown in
> LibreOffice, choose Tools - Options - LibreOffice Writer - Print and
> select the In margins option in the Comments area. The exported pages
> will be scaled down and the comments will be placed into their
> margins.

But it fact setting the option above does not really change the output, no comments are presented in the PDF, either as annotations or margin prints.

How can it be done? I am using LibreOffice 6.4.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on Export as PDF, on the PDF Options window, select "Comments as PDF annotations".

[image: IMG:]

The comments will be displayed on the margins plus as annotations when viewing the pdf document.

[image]

Comment: This dialogue box does not appear for me when I click export as PDF.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs What dialogbox are you talking about?